# Can the Jackson parser be used to parse JSON5?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jvm, json5

We'd like to parse [JSON5](https://json5.org/) documents in the JVM, but [the JSON5-specific libraries available on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=json5&type=Repositories) all appear to have very low support. As parsers are often magnets for security vulnerabilities, we'd prefer not to use a parser that isn't already being widely used and scrutinised by the community.

This got us to wondering: Can the optional features of the [Jackson JSON parser](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) be used to parse JSON5?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## tl;dr

By enabling the following optional Jackson parser features:

- `ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES`
- `ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA`
- `ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES`
- `ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER`
- `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS`
- `ALLOW_JAVA_COMMENTS`
- `ALLOW_LEADING_DECIMAL_POINT_FOR_NUMBERS`

it seems possible to support all of JSON5's headline features except for:

- hexadecimal numbers
- trailing decimal points on numbers
- plus signs before numbers
- extra whitespace characters

## Detail

Jackson has [a number of optional features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki/JsonReadFeatures) which can be enabled on a parser to make it more lenient in the way it parses.

### Supported Features

Comparing these parser options to the headline features of JSON5, we find that the following are supported:

> Object keys may be an ECMAScript 5.1 IdentifierName.

✅ Supported with the `ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` feature

> Objects may have a single trailing comma.

> Arrays may have a single trailing comma.

✅ Both supported with the `ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA` feature

> Strings may be single quoted.

✅ Supported with the `ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES` feature

> Strings may span multiple lines by escaping new line characters.
>
> Strings may include character escapes.

✅ Both of these [appear to be supported](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/612#issuecomment-835310454) by Jackson's `ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER` feature, though the meaning or purpose of escaping here may differ subtly. *DYOR*.

> Numbers may be IEEE 754 positive infinity, negative infinity, and NaN.

✅ Supported with the `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` feature

> Single and multi-line comments are allowed.

✅ Supported with the `ALLOW_JAVA_COMMENTS` feature.

### Partially Supported Features

The following JSON5 feature is *partially* supported by Jackson:

> Numbers may have a leading or trailing decimal point.

✅ Leading decimal points are supported with the `ALLOW_LEADING_DECIMAL_POINT_FOR_NUMBERS` feature.

⛔️ Jackson doesn't appear to have support for trailing decimal points.

### Unsupported Features

There doesn't currently (mid-2021) appear to be any way to configure Jackson to permit the following JSON5 features:

> Numbers may be hexadecimal.
>
> Numbers may have a trailing decimal point.
>
> Numbers may begin with an explicit plus sign.

> Additional white space characters are allowed.

Comment: Thanks Graham! I was trying to use JSON5 too.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript developers, you could use [jsonc-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser) which is developed by Microsoft. `jsonc-parser` could be use in browser and node.js environment.

Here's an example that demonstrates how to use the "jsonc-parser" npm package to parse a JSON5 string:

```js
import * as jsonc from 'jsonc-parser';

const jsonString = `{
    // This is a JSON5 string!
    "name": 'John Doe',
    "age": 42,
    "isMarried": false,
    "pets": [
        {
            "name": 'Fluffy',
            "type": 'cat'
        }
    ]
}`;

const parsedJson = jsonc.parse(jsonString);

console.log(parsedJson);
```

Online Demo: [JSON5 parser](http://json-5.com)

Answer (score 0):

Graham Lea's answer was great.

Here I'll add a couple of improvements Jackson has made in recent years.

- `ALLOW_TRAILING_DECIMAL_POINT_FOR_NUMBERS`*(Since 2.14)*: Numbers may have a trailing decimal point.
- `ALLOW_LEADING_PLUS_SIGN_FOR_NUMBERS`*(Since 2.14)*: Numbers may begin with an explicit plus sign.